# Let $P(z)=\displaystyle{\sum}_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k$ with $a_0,...,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ Prove if $P(\alpha)=0$ then $P(\bar{\alpha})=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P(z)=\displaystyle{\sum}_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k$ with $a_0,...,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ Prove if $P(\alpha)=0$ then $P(\bar{\alpha})=0$

**My attempt:**
Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha=x+iy$. Let $\bar{\alpha}$ the conjugate of alpha

$\displaystyle{\sum}_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k=0$ implies that $a_0+a_1z+...a_nz^n=0$

Here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Comment: Hint : start from $0 = a_0 + a_1 \alpha + a_2 \alpha^2 + \ldots + a_n \alpha^n$, and then take the conjugate on both sides of your equation.

Comment: More generally, $\overline{P(z)} = P(\overline{z})$.  Just look at it term by term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following properties for $z, w \in \mathbb C$:

$$\overline {zw} = \bar z \bar w$$

$$\overline {z + w} = \overline z + \overline w$$